# Can O(N+NM) be simplified to O(NM)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Suppose that `N` and `M` are two parameters of an algorithm. Is the following simplification correct?

```
O(N+NM) = O[N(1+M)] = O(NM)
```

In other words, is it allowed to remove the constant in such a context?

Comment: The equality is correct. Just depends on how precise you want to show the complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes

**Explanation**

By the definition of the Big-Oh notation, if a term inside the O(.) is provably smaller than a constant times another term for all sufficiently large values of the variable, then you can drop the smaller term.

You can find a more precise definition of Big-Oh [here](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html), but some example consequences are that:

- O(1000*N+N^2) = O(N^2) since N^2 will dwarf 1000*N as soon as N>1000
- O(N+M) cannot be simplified
- O(N+NM) = O(NM) since N+NM < 2(NM) as soon as N>1 and M>1

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, you cannot get rid of the `N` term if `M=0`. so let's assume `M>0`. Take a constant `k > 0` such that `1<=kM` (if `M` is integer, `k=1`, otherwise take a constant `c` such that `0 < c <= M` an take `k=1/c`). We have

```
N+NM  = N(1+M)
     <= N(kM+M)            ; 1<=kM
      = (k+1)NM
      ∊ O(NM)
```

On the other hand,

```
NM <= N+NM ∊ O(N+NM)
```

Hence the equality.

Comment: Nice precise answer.